# Electronic Switch with Load Before and After

Tags: voltage, transistors, switches, circuit-design

I'm having trouble including a switch in a circuit that will be turned on and off via a PIC microcontroller (3.3v). The circuit that it will be switching can go up to 24v and around 20amps. This has been easy to do with a transistor (N-Channel MOSFET) and works very nicely when I put the load before the switch.

The problem is that this switch will control an external circuit where the load could be anywhere. Having the load after the switch causes a voltage drop of around 10%, something I need to get around. Is there a way of getting consistent voltage and current on the second circuit before and after the switch? It doesn't have to be a MOSFET.

Comment: Is a MOSFAT a heavy duty MOSFET? You need to supply a schematic so we know what you're talking about. There's a button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: It has a phat junction... sp. err. corrected

Comment: They're primarily used in phat sounding bass amplifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a mechanical relay - provides full isolation between the microcontroller and the switched circuit, so you can place the relay contacts anywhere you wish in the switched circuit.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6sfca.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Here we have a regulated "voltage source (low) power supply with a known drop in voltage due to a rise in current due to internal resistance for example,  shown as 0.01 Ohm.

> We call this the effective series resistance (ESR) or the output impedance Zout.

- An ideal switch with a 1 Ohm load will drop 1% due to resistor divider.
- If the RdsOn of the switch is equal to,  or higher than the Zout from the supply, then Voltage drop will increase even more.

> We call this **Load Regulation error** and it equal to the ratio of source to (load+source) impedance, like any voltage divider.  Therefore it is a good idea to choose the switch according to the % load regulation you need.

One must know the switched and steady currents of the load to determine the effect R values of the load.  The FET or relay contact resistance can be selected based on load current rating.

Normally a much higher current rating in FETs is chosen to minimize the resistance if you want good load regulation.

- A "High Side" switch is shown needs a low Vg to switch on thus a P-ch MOSFET is used.
- If using  "Low-side" switch on Gnd to load then V+ , we use an N-ch switch when there is only a single supply.
- Distributors carry both for automotive and industrial use in high power switch applications.
- For 24V,20A  you may choose a 30A relay or a 60A MOSFET depending on load inductance, it may need further margin derating.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STL62P3LLH6/497-15481-1-ND/5244758

- specs: 62A 30V , 10.5 mOhm @ 7A, 10V   ($0.91/1pc)
- SMD only